# Identifying position of an item in select list when removing

Tags: jquery, html

I add/remove elements from a select list using jquery like:

```
var options = $('#example').attr('options');
options[options.length] = new Option('Item1');
```

is there a way to saving the inded(position) of a removed item and adding an new item at a that position?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your code is calling some sort of function, and does not make much sense to the rest of us at all, but to remove an element and replace it with another element you can always do:

```
$('option', 'select').eq(3) //select fourth option and replace it
                     .replaceWith($('<option id="newOption">New Stuff</option>'));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MQqD8/)

Comment: are you talking about Option()?

Comment: Well, yes! You are removing elements you say, but all we see is you getting some atribute called options into an array?? and calling a new instance of some function on one of those options. It really has nothing to do with the question ?

Comment: yes, it is storing options in array "option" and then inserting "Item1" as the last item. I want to insert it at a specific location which is not fixed, I forgot to mention that, but when I remove an item from the list is there a way to finding the index(position) of that item and inserting the new item at that position? Also, "Option()" is a jquery function which I use to adding new options. Here is where I got it from:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-add-option-select-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with adeneo code , incase you want to remove the option with certain value

```
    $('#somename').find('option[value=7]').replaceWith($('<option id="newOption"> New Stuff</option>'));
```

Html Part

```
    <select name="somename" id="somename">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
    <option value="6"> 6 </option>
    <option value="7"> 7 </option>
    <option value="8"> 8 </option>
</select>
```